# Service command for Nginx is not working properly after Passenger repository imported

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

I'm running a Nginx web server under Ubuntu 14.04.

Recently, I imported the repository from Phusion Passenger to run GitLab, and my Nginx from Launchpad was replaced by the one from the new repository. (I'm running GitLab with my own Nginx and Apache instead of the embedded servers.)

```
frederick@Ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-cache showpkg nginx | head -n3
Package: nginx
Versions:
1:1.8.0-8.5.0.15~trusty1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com_apt_passenger_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
```

Then the weird thing began. Every time after I rebooted the machine, `sudo service nginx xxxx` became invalid. However, if I use `/etc/init.d/nginx`, it works like a charm.

```
frederick@Ubuntu:~$ sudo service nginx status
nginx stop/waiting

frederick@Ubuntu:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx status
 * nginx is running

frederick@Ubuntu:~$ sudo service nginx reload
reload: Unknown instance:

frederick@Ubuntu:~$ cat /run/nginx.pid
3389

frederick@Ubuntu:~$ ps aux | grep [n]ginx
root      3389  0.0  0.7 158636 15404 ?        Ss   15:11   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
www-data  4713  0.0  0.4 158636  8824 ?        S    15:36   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  4714  0.0  0.4 158636  8824 ?        S    15:36   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  4715  0.0  0.4 158636  8824 ?        S    15:36   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  4716  0.0  0.4 158636  8824 ?        S    15:36   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

It seems that the `service` command is not running the script of `/etc/init.d/nginx` . I have to run `sudo nginx -s stop && sudo service nginx start` to enable it again.

I'm really confused now. Please help, thanks.

***UPDATE***

/etc/init.d/nginx from Launchpad: https://goo.gl/cEHtf7

/etc/init.d/nginx from Passenger(now): https://goo.gl/Ig1az5

/etc/init/nginx.conf are the same: https://goo.gl/aq1dUv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed the `/etc/init/nginx.conf` and it's ok now.

It seems that the package from Launchpad Nginx official is using System V init script while the one from Passenger repository is using Upstart.

Maybe I should turn to Upstart totally.